# link_to inside file inside app folder rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, link-to

I have a file called **messages_datatables.rb** inside `/app/datatables/admin/`

```
class Admin::MessagesDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view
  .
  .
  .
  private
  def data
    messages.map do |message|
      [
        "", 
        link_to(message.subject, admin_message_path(message))
      ]
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
  .
end
```

I need use `link_to` helper inside this file but I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `admin_message_path' for #<Admin::MessagesDatatable:0xbe07170>):
```

The path is working fine in views. I have the path in my routes.

**Where have I the error?**

Comment: Do you have the admin_message path? You can check by executing `rake routes` in your command line. There should be a line containing `admin_message`. You can also check your routes.rb if there is a route  with something like `:as => 'admin_message'`

Comment: Restart your web app server and try again after you change your routes

Comment: I wonder if the helper code for routes needs to be included before the class.

Comment: Thank you but after restart the server still not working...

Comment: I'm guessing the *_path and *_url methods are defined somewhere else in a module or class which your class does not include or extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes'
```

And instead of `admin_message_path`, use `url_helpers.admin_message_path`

Comment: Thank you, this working fine if the app have not `params[:locale]`. My app use params locale inside routes something like `scope '(:locale)' do ...resources... end` I have tried with `link_to(message.subject url_helpers.admin_message_path(params[:locale], message))` but I get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'link_to' for #<Admin::MessagesDatatable:0xc0d7288>):`

Comment: You shouldn't create an object aware of the full stack.

Comment: I am following this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables, where I can see how it works but `link_to` is not working for me!

Comment: I can't see why link_to isn't recognized in your case. But you should pass params another way

Comment: The problem was fixed. Now is working fine with `link_to(message.subject url_helpers.admin_message_path(params[:locale], message))`. Thank you very much!